# Auto incrementing composite primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a database that includes an incident table along with a violation table. The primary key of the Incident Table is IncidentID. Then the primary key of the violation table is IncidentID,ViolationNum.

```
CREATE TABLE Incident (
IncidentID FLOAT,
Plate VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
PlateState INTEGER NOT NULL,
IncidentTypeID INTEGER NOT NULL,
CommonPlaceID INTEGER NOT NULL,
Officer INTEGER,
DateStart DATE NOT NULL,
DateEnd DATE,
Comments TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY (IncidentID),
FOREIGN KEY (Plate, PlateState) REFERENCES Vehicle (Plate, PlateState),
FOREIGN KEY (IncidentTypeID) REFERENCES IncidentTypeLookUp (IncidentTypeID),
FOREIGN KEY (CommonPlaceID) REFERENCES CommonPlace (CommonPlaceID),
FOREIGN KEY (Officer) REFERENCES Officer (BadgeNumber));

CREATE TABLE Violation (
IncidentID float,
ViolationNum INTEGER,
ViolationTypeID INTEGER NOT NULL,
DateOfViolation DATE NOT NULL,
Comments TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY (IncidentID,ViolationNum),
FOREIGN KEY (IncidentID) REFERENCES Incident (IncidentID),
FOREIGN KEY (ViolationTypeID) REFERENCES ViolationTypeLookUp (ViolationTypeID));
```

The goal is to have violation number increment by 1 for each IncidentID
ex.
2020001,1
2020001,2
2020001,3
2020002,1
2020002,2

I have coded the following triggers each with their own errors.

```
create trigger violationCounter 
on violation
instead of insert
as 
begin   
declare @iid float
declare @vnum int
declare @vtid int
declare @date date
declare @comm text

select @iid=IncidentID from inserted
select @vtid=ViolationTypeID from inserted
select @date = DateOfViolation from inserted
select @comm = comments from inserted

IF NOT EXISTS (Select * from Violation where IncidentID=@iid)
set @vnum = 1
else 
set @vnum = (select max(ViolationNum)+1
                from Violation
                where IncidentID = @iid)

insert into Violation 
values (@iid,@vnum,@vtid,@date,@comm) 
end 
go
```

This Trigger doesn't accept Violation as an object in the "@vnum=" select statement.

OR

```
create trigger violationcounter
on Violation

instead of insert

as
begin

begin transaction

declare @iid float
declare @vnum int

IF EXISTS  (Select * from Violation where @iid=IncidentID)
set @vnum = (select max(ViolationNum)+1
                from Violation
                where IncidentID = @iid);
else 
set @vnum = 1;

INSERT INTO Violation (IncidentID,ViolationNum, ViolationTypeID,DateOfViolation,Comments)
SELECT IncidentID, @vnum, ViolationTypeID, DateOfViolation,Comments
FROM inserted

Commit transaction

end
```

This Trigger is accepted but when entering data it doesn't increment violationNum.

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Fix your data model so the violation table has its own primary key -- `identity`.  You can still have the other columns as attributes, but they don't need to be part of the key.

Comment: I agree with Gordon. Don't try to do this with triggers. Use an `Identity` column as the Primary key in each table. I would argue against storing the violation number, rather just calculate it and present it at runtime. You are already logging a timestamp for each violation, so I would just generate a violation number in order of that time partitioned by the incident id.

Comment: Thanks!! I was getting frustrated because my teacher for my database class told me to structure it like this and I couldn't get it to work. My teacher is just wrong I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The correct implementation for this is to generate the ViolationNum using a Sequence or IDENTITY, even if you keep it as the second column in a compound primary key.  EG:

```
CREATE TABLE Violation (
IncidentID INTEGER,
ViolationNum INTEGER IDENTITY NOT NULL,
ViolationTypeID INTEGER NOT NULL,
DateOfViolation DATE NOT NULL,
Comments TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY (IncidentID,ViolationNum),
FOREIGN KEY (IncidentID) REFERENCES Incident (IncidentID),
FOREIGN KEY (ViolationTypeID) REFERENCES ViolationTypeLookUp (ViolationTypeID));
```

And forget about ViolationNum values starting over for each IncidentID.